# org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.google.protobuf.HBaseZeroCopyByteString cannot

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

Getting below exception while executing HBase client inside spark job:org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.google.protobuf.HBaseZeroCopyByteString cannot

Answer (score 0):

Set Spark configuration => spark.driver.extraClassPath", "hbase-protocol-0.96.2-hadoop2.jar.

Code: 
.setConf("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "hbase-protocol-0.96.2-hadoop2.jar")